# Why can't I login in as the ftp user?

Tags: users, su

After installing vsftpd I have the user ftp on my system. I assigned a password to this account. However, I still cannot login as the ftp user (on the command line, without any ftp-protocol involved).

```
su - ftp
password:
... still the previous user is logged on
```

People will wonder why I want to do this. Well, I want to expose the whole file system via ftp. People will say, you should not do that, well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is very likely due to the `ftp` account having `/bin/false` or similar as its default shell:

```
$ getent passwd ftp
ftp:x:116:127:ftp daemon,,,:/srv/ftp:/bin/false
```

It is probably not a good idea in term of security but should you want to set the user shell to something valid, you can use `chsh`, eg:

```
# chsh ftp /bin/bash
chsh ftp
Changing the login shell for ftp
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
Login Shell [/bin/false]: /bin/bash
```

Comment: thx, "sudo usermod -s /bin/bash ftp" did it.

Comment: chsh, learning, thx

Comment: You're welcome, `usermod` is fine too !